# NHibernate Evict By type And Id From First Level Cache

Tags: c#, nhibernate, caching

I Have a Nhibernate object called Car, this Car object have a PersietentBag IList collection called Doors, all in lazy loading.

if i do (IN SESSION 1)

```
int singleDoor = Car.Doors[0];
```

the lazyest collections loads from db and the related objects becomes added to the first level cache, the i will have in the 1rst level cache N objects Car and N Doors loaded from db.

From another hand (at other part of the code IN SESSION 2) i loads the same Car objects and do the same assigment

```
int singleDoor = Car,Doors[0];
```

and i Evicts Car and all the Door(s) objects from SESSION2

i modify the state of this objects and want to attach the doscontected objects tu the SESSION1 for save nd do

```
mySession.Update(Car);
```

But when i try to update the Door(s) obejcts obviously i have the (an other obejct with the same id, etc) exception is thrown because there's yet another object with the same id.

Bot it's dificult to find the old object to evict, how can i EVICT the old objects or clear the 1rst level cache (only by type and id) or discard old objects from cache and update what i want?.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't because of the second level cache, it's because you're trying to save the entity from session 2 when it's already been loaded in session 1 (in fact it's the first level cache that's causing this).

The answer to your question is to use (in session 1), session.Evict(car), however that's not really the best approach - I would rather suggest using session.Merge(car) which will update the persistent object in session 1 without throwing the exception about another object with the same id.

Comment: Thanks, i corrected the error, it's the 1st level cache, in fact session.Evict(Car) is not the best approach, however i don't have in hand the old Car object to Evict, with the Merge approach, if i have state changes at old Car, the 2 Cars state changes have merged? or the old Car state changes go lost? i need to discard old Car state, thank in advance.

Comment: You could do session.Get<Car>(id) to get it from the session and then evict it, however if it wasn't in the session in the first place this would cause an unnecessary load from the db.  Session.Merge will overwrite the old car state with the new one - ie. it will discard the old car state (if you want it to merge any child collections also then you need to set the collection cascade to "merge")